# Using modular arithmetics for interval

Tags: javascript, carousel, modulo, infinite

Let's say we have range [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3] which can be described as  MIN_VALUE=-2  and  MAX_VALUE=3
We want to implement function called infiniteCarousel() which will accept **any number** and used modulo operator (or somthing else) in order to calculate corresponding number in specified range.

```
function infiniteCarousel(value, minValue, maxValue)
{
    // todo
    // use modulus operator to calculate correct number
    // return calculated number 
}


// range = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
const MIN_VALUE = -2;
const MAX_VALUE = 3;

var array = [];

// let's calculate number from -10 to 10
for (var i = -10; i<10; i++)
{
    array.push( infiniteCarousel(i, MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE) );
}

// should print [2, 3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -2]
console.log(array);
```

Do you know any efficient way to implement this?
Also, does anybody know what is the correct name for this problem? I am having troubles searching web because I don't know how to properly describe this problem.

Comment: Simplify the problem (a lot) by norming the interval to always start at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the `offset`, if `value` is smaller than `minValue` take `maxValue`, otherwise `minValue`.

Then adjust `value` with the offset, take the remainder with the `count` of the items and use the offset for getting the value in the wanted range.

```js
function infiniteCarousel(value, minValue, maxValue) {
    var count = maxValue - minValue + 1,
        offset = value <= minValue ? maxValue : minValue;
        
    return (value - offset) % count + offset;
}

var array = [];
for (var i = -10; i < 10; i++) array.push(infiniteCarousel(i, -2, 3));

console.log(...[2, 3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]);
console.log(...array);

array = [];
for (var i = -10; i < 10; i++) array.push(infiniteCarousel(i, 2, 6));

console.log(...[5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4]);
console.log(...array);
```

Comment: Great solution. It does not work for positive intervals like MIN_VALUE=2 and MAX_VALUE=6

Comment: what resutl do you want from this values?

Comment: For MIN_VALUE=2 and MAX_VALUE=6 the output should be [5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4] from -10 to 10